# How to connect with an Axis webservice hosted in a password protected realm?

Tags: authentication, web-services, client, wsdl2java

I'm trying to connect with a webservice that's in a password protected host, i.e. you must enter user+pass to access the remote WSDL.

The key word there is "trying", I have a client made by WSDL2JAVA that works ok if the service is unprotected, but I can't find how to add the login to that code.

To clarify, it's not the webservice who demands authentication, but the site itself.  I'm testing with a secured realm in a tomcat server, but I'm lookin for a platform independent solution.

Has anybody been able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

First create a HttpClient object and authenticate it, as explained [here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/httpclient/how-to-use-basic-authentication.html).  Then without closing that connection, connect with the webservice as usual.

And that's it.  I'm not sure *why* that works, I think that the java process saves the connection cookie or something like that.